# seq - invalid floating point argument error

Tags: bash, unix, seq

I'm currently writing a small bash file to search specific information on a file.
I need a for structure and I'm using "seq" but I keep getting "invalid floating point argument error : 4" and I do not know how to solve it.

When I try to do some arithmetic operation on my variable nmbretry, I get a arithmetic operator not available.

If you have any ideas how to solve it!

Here my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
nmbretry=`grep -c 'retry for the 1 times' /home/leconte/dossierpartage/business.log`
echo "Number of retry is $nmbretry"
let $nmbretry + 1
for i in `seq 0 $nmbretry`; do echo $i 
done;
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I guess you want something like `let num=$nmbretry+1`

Comment: or maybe `((nmbretry++))`

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49861/seq-invalid-floating-point-argument-error

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

The error was that I used notepad on Windows than use it on Unix. It did not like the "transfer".

I do everything on Unix and now it's work!

Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

increment nmbretry with `let ++nmbretry` - bash also has a counted for loop:

```
for((i=0; i < nmbretry; ++i)); do
  echo $i
done
```